# How to replicate the SMALL() function of Excel in python

Tags: python-3.x, excel-formula

Let say I have below array in excel

[image]

When I apply Excel's `SMALL` function as `small(array, 4.5)`, I get result as 50

Is there any equivalent function/method available in Excel?

Documentation of Excel's `SMALL()` function can be available in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/small-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07

Comment: *"Is there any equivalent function/method available in Excel?"*: I don't understand. You just provided it. What is the link with Python? What would be the input you have in Python? Do you want to use Python to read Excel files?

Comment: @trincot I assumed it was just a typo, since in the title OP ask for a equivalent function in python and asking for a Excel function doesn't really make sense. Clarification would be nice though...

Comment: Why use 4.5 in the example? Looks like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box, but its pretty easy to implements with `sorted` or `heapq.nsmallest`

```py
import heapq

data_1 = [3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7]
data_2 = [1, 4, 8, 3, 7, 12, 54, 8, 23]

def smallest_sorted(array, k):
    k = int(k)
    return sorted(array)[k - 1]  # -1 since, indexing starts from 0

print(smallest_sorted(data_1, 4))
print(smallest_sorted(data_2, 2))

def smallest_heapq(array, k):
    k = int(k)
    return heapq.nsmallest(k, array)[-1]

print(smallest_heapq(data_1, 4))
print(smallest_heapq(data_2, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code. It takes your data, makes a copy (so it won't change global variable), deletes smallest values until it reaches 'k' position. Then it returns k smallest value. I added n variable to make it more readable, because python counts from 0, not 1.

```
data = [5, 10, 15, 20, 30]
k = 3 

def small(list):
    n = k - 1 
    list = data.copy()
    for _ in range(n):
        list.remove(min(list))
    return min(list)

print(small(data))
print(data)
```